# Multi-Site/Application IIS in Hyper-V

Tags: iis, hyper-v

As a developer, I have been tasked with creating a new development environment. Currently, our dev environment has 5 different VMS with IIS hosting multiple sites and applications.

I don't know the origin of this choice, but assuming there is no technical requirement that these be on different IIS instances, wouldn't it be more efficient to have everything on a single instance? Doesn't IIS have a proven performance record in multi-tenant situations for web hosting companies?

Comment: The word "efficient" is the key in your question.  If have a different IP address per site then you skip the "host header" section of IIS processing.  Host header processing IS overhead, however "most likely" superficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's more efficient to have everything on a single IIS server. Why do you want to manage 5 Windows Servers instead of 1, unless you need load balancing/HA ?

Additionally, it's a development environment, you'll probably not hit performance issues here.

You can take a look at [Tuning IIS 10.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/role/web-server/tuning-iis-10) if you are looking for tips/recommended settings.